# How can I create an array in .js using const so that I can use that array for creating a row of cards?

Tags: reactjs

So I have to create a row of cards and each card needs to have unique information in it. I understood that I will have to use an array and then map it in order to do so. I am using hooks so I am creating this within a function instead of a class. So how can I create an array using const and then map it so that my cards can read it and display it on my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

here in this first set the state value to an empty array after that by using setArray you can add values to this array, it can be an object, string depends on your need.

```
import React from "react";
const [array,setArray] = React.useState([]);
setArray([{
          key:1,
          message:"Here you can add your on object"},
           {key:2,
           message:"Its can have many key value pairs in an oject depending on your requirement."});

function UseArray(arrayData){
     console.log(arrayData.message);
}

array.map(UseArray);
```